# "Uncaught [object Object] thrown - zone.js" error thrown when mocking response (Angular2)

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

A strange error is happening, apparently when I try to mock a particular HTTP response using Angular2 / Jasmine. I've narrowed this down that when I have a call to `httpMock.mockResponse` it happens, and if I comment it out, it does not.

The error is just:

```
zone.js:260 Uncaught [object Object] thrown
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:260
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
```

There is no further information given though.  Any ideas how to start to debug such an error?

I am using Chome DevTools to test.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when in your module (or test) is necessary to add (in imports) all the services that your component use.

For example, if you use forms on your component so, you need to add to the module (or test if you are doing a test)

```
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
```